# How can I passing data from jquery codes to my project backend

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I did create a form and A submit button in my website

but I do not know How can I passing data from javascript codes to My asp.net core codes

My Html jquery css codes Here:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    padding:20px 25px 70px 25px;
}
#all-questions-preview>.content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container{
    width:100%;
    background: #fefefe;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding:12px 18px 70px 18px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container>.question-title{
    color: #444;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container>.question-title::before{
    content: ":.";
}

#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container>.close{
    position:absolute;
    padding:5px;
    color: #f02f24;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    border:none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

}
#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container input{
    background: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    border:none;
    font-weight: bold;

}
#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container .question-sentence{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    font-size:1.2em;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #71c9db;
    color: #61adbb;
}
#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container .answer-span{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:20%;
    min-width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    /*text-align: right;*/
    /*border:1px solid red;*/
}
#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container .answer-input{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #e171ae;
    color: #be3e89;
    width:calc(100% - 50px)
}
#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container .answer-span .close{
    position:absolute;
    padding:5px;
    color: #f02f24;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top:15px;
    right:22px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

#all-questions-preview>.content>.question-container .add-answer{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:15px;
    background-color: rgba(243, 200, 86, 0.48);
    border:2px solid rgb(221, 177, 84);
    color: rgb(153, 122, 58);
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right:15px;
    bottom:10px;
}
#all-questions-preview> .add-question{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(60, 243, 71, 0.48);
    border:2px solid rgb(69, 198, 59);
    color: rgb(32, 114, 31);
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -62px;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
#all-questions-preview> .submit{
    display: block;
    width:90%;
    margin:15px auto 15px auto;

    background-color: rgba(74, 148, 243, 0.48);
    border:2px solid rgb(74, 148, 243);
    color: rgb(39, 77, 127);
    padding:15px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 1px rgba(61, 122, 200, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="all-questions-preview">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <button class="add-question" type="button">Add new question</button>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <form action="test.php" id="all-questions-main" method="post" style="display: none">
            <input type="hidden" name="data" id="questions-data">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            createQuestion($('#all-questions-preview')); //default one question added
            $('#all-questions-preview').on('submit', previewFormSubmit);
            $('#all-questions-preview .add-question').on('click', addQuestion);

        });

        function previewFormSubmit(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            let data = [];
            getQuestions($(this)).each(function() {
                let question = $(this);
                let question_data = {};
                question_data['question_sentence'] = question.find('.question-sentence').eq(0).val();
                let question_answers = [];
                getAnswers(question).each(function() {
                    let answer = $(this);
                    let answer_input = answer.find('.answer-input').val();
                    if (answer_input.trim() !== "") {
                        question_answers.push(answer_input)
                    }
                });
                question_data['question_answers'] = question_answers;
                data.push(question_data);
            });
            $('#all-questions-main>#questions-data').val(JSON.stringify(data));
            $('#all-questions-main')[0].submit();
        }


        function addAnswer(event) {

            let question_container = $(this).parents('.question-container').eq(0);
            createAnswer(question_container);
        }

        function createAnswer(question_container) {
            let answers = getAnswers(question_container);
            let answer_span = $("<span>").addClass('answer-span');
            let closeBtn = null;
            if (answers.length > 0) {
                closeBtn = $("<button>").attr({
                    type: 'button',
                    class: 'close'
                }).text('+').on('click', deleteAnswer);
            }
            let answer_input = $("<input>").addClass('answer-input').attr({
                type: 'text',
                name: 'answer',
                placeholder: 'answer' + (answers.length + 1)
            });
            if (answers.length === 0) {
                answer_input.attr('required', 'required')
            }
            let container_answers = question_container.find('.answers-container').eq(0);
            answer_span.append(closeBtn, answer_input);
            container_answers.append(answer_span);
            return answer_span;
        }

        function getAnswers(question_container) {
            return (question_container.find(".answers-container .answer-span"));

        }


        function addQuestion(event) {
            let all_questions_form = $(this).parents("#all-questions-preview").eq(0);
            createQuestion(all_questions_form);
        }

        function getQuestions(all_question_form) {
            return (all_question_form.find('.question-container'));
        }

        function createQuestion(all_questions_form) {
            let all_questions_form_content = all_questions_form.find(">.content").eq(0);
            let questions = getQuestions(all_questions_form);
            let new_question = $("<div>").addClass('question-container');
            let question_title = $("<h4>").addClass('question-title').text('Question number' + (questions.length + 1));
            let closeBtn = null;
            if (questions.length > 0) {
                closeBtn = $("<button>").attr({
                    type: 'button',
                    class: 'close'
                }).text('+').on('click', deleteQuestion);
            }
            let question_sentence = $("<input>").addClass('question-sentence').attr({
                type: 'text',
                name: 'question_sentence',
                placeholder: 'question' + (questions.length + 1),
                required: 'required'
            });
            let container_answers = $("<div>").addClass('answers-container');
            let add_answer_btn = $("<button>").addClass('add-answer').attr('type', 'button').text('Add answer').on('click', addAnswer);

            new_question.append(question_title, closeBtn, question_sentence, container_answers, add_answer_btn);
            all_questions_form_content.append(new_question);
            createAnswer(new_question);
            return new_question;
        }


        function deleteQuestion() {
            let question_container = $(this).parents('.question-container').eq(0);
            let all_questions_form = $(this).parents("#all-questions-preview").eq(0);
            let questions = getQuestions(all_questions_form);
            if (questions.index(question_container) !== 0) {
                question_container.fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            }
        }

        function deleteAnswer() {
            let question_container = $(this).parents('.question-container').eq(0);
            let answer_span = $(this).parents('.answer-span').eq(0);
            let all_questions_form = $(this).parents("#all-questions-preview").eq(0);
            let answers = getAnswers(question_container);
            if (answers.index(answer_span) !== 0) {
                answer_span.fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                })
            }
        }
    </script>



</body>

</html>
```

In fact I want when The user clicks submit button The Data passes To Asp.net core codes

Please help me, I have been involved in this issue for several days

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the reason why you can't get the model in backend code.

Because the data you passed is string format, so we can install`Newtonsoft.Json` library. And deserialize the string to object.

```
public class list_questions { 
    public string question_sentence { get; set; }
    public List<string> question_answers { get; set; }
}
```

## STEPS

In your .cshtml, you code should like below.

```
 <form action="/ForTest/get_data" id="all-questions-main" method="post" style="display: none">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" id="questions-data">
 </form>
```

[image]

*My `/ForTest/get_data` method*

[image]

***My test result***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Binding model does not happen in your `HTML` that is sent to the action method with a submit . You can transfer array question and answer  with Ajax.